# Error when adding JakeWharton project from github to my android project.?

Tags: android

I am getting a red cross mark in my project in project explorer when I add this as a [Library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator).My sample code is working properly.Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your java compiler is set to proper JDK version also clean project.

Comment: @VendettaDroid Java compiler level is set to 1.6

Comment: @VendettaDroid The error is fixed.The problem was the  android-support-v4.jar  file in Library project was different from my project.I just changed the replaced the  android-support-v4.jar .

Comment: you should put your answer and mark it as fixed. It will help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try These:**

1. Android: Project Build Path must be API 14+
2. JAVA Compiler must be 1.6
3. Support Libraries(jar files) must be same

Comment: I have changed but still a red exclamatory mark exist in my package explorer.

Comment: It is saying jar miss match.Can I get this working in Api level 9.

Comment: Oh. Just check if the **android-support-v4.jar** in libs folder of the library and your project have the same size. If they are different try replacing 1 of them with the other.

Comment: Thankyou very much. By replacing the android-support-v4.jar the bug was fixed.Thankyou....